# Encrypting only a small part of my hard-drive

Tags: encryption, windows

In Windows 10, I can encrypt the entire hard-drive with bitlocker. However, it makes some programs run too slowly. In fact, most of my hard-drive is not secret: these are just data files and documents that I intend to publish anyway. The only thing I can think of that is really secret is the file in which my browser keeps the passwords. For such a small file, it seems wasteful to encrypt an entire hard-drive. My questions are:

1. Are there other parts of a standard Windows system that should be encrypted, besides the browser password file?
2. What is an easy way to encrypt only those files, while keeping the rest of the hard-drive unencrypted and fast?

Comment: Most browsers encrypt the stored passwords for you *as long as you set a master password*.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

> 1. Right-click on the folder you want to encrypt and go to Properties
> 2. On the General tab, click the Advanced button
> 3. Under Compress and encrypt attributes section, click on Encrypt content to secure data encrypt files windows 10
> 4. Click OK and close Properties window
> 5. Apply changes to the folder, subfolders, and files when prompted
>    That’s that, your folder is now encrypted and its text is shown in green color.

[Source.](https://windowsreport.com/encrypt-files-folders-windows-10/)

**Method 2:**

Use a tool to do it like ***Gilisoft File Lock Pro*** for example

Comment: This does not answer *what* should be encrypted. The OP states that all the user files are classed as public. Can you use your method on System32?